# DDPG not converging for a simple control problem

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, policy-gradient-descent

I am trying to solve a control problem with DDPG. The problem is simple enough so that I can do value function iteration for its discretized version, and thus I have the "perfect" solution to compare my results with. But I want to solve the problem with DDPG, in hope to apply RL to harder versions of it.

**Some details about the problem**:

1. The control space is [0,1], the state space has dimension 2
2. This is a stochastic environment, transitions between states are not deterministic
3. There is some non-constant reward at any period, so sparse rewards should not be a problem
4. Value function iteration takes just 10 minutes or so, again, it's quite a simple control problem

**What is the issue**:

My agent always eventually converges to a degenerate policy with action being either always 1 or 0. At some point while training it can be a bit close to the right policy, but it's never really close.

Similarly, I usually fail to get right the shape of Q-function:

[image: Q-value for a typical state as a function of action]

**What I tried to do**:

1. I put a sigmoid layer at the end of the actor network (naturally, as the control space is [0,1])
2. I have target networks both for policy and critic
3. I clap my actions so they are between [0.01, 0.99] (the perfect solution is always within these boundaries)
4. I tried adding some artificial penalty to reward for actions close 0 and 1. Then, the algorithm converged to something else, but again not to something good.
5. I tried both random uniform exploration or adding small normal noise. I either decrease exploration rate with time or hold it constant but small
6. To check my code, I ran the following experiment. I would first fix policy to be the "perfect" one and update only critic. In this case, I manage to learn Q-network pretty well (the shape too). Then, I freeze the critic and update only actor with the DDPG updating rule. I manage to get pretty close to the perfect policy. But when I start to update actor and critic simultaneously, they again diverge to something degenerate.
7. I experimented a lot with my hyperparameters, currently they are the following:

```
> Optimizer: Adam. Learning rates: 0.001 for actor, 0.01 for critic. Batch size = 50,
> memory size = 10,000.  Standard deviation of normal exploration noise = 0.02.
> Weight for soft updates of target networks: 0.01. 
> Sizes of hidden layers for actor and critic: [8,16,16,8].
> Length of simulation: from 1,000 to 1,000,000.
```

I would be very grateful for any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced [this problem](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/22634/21181) and changing the model, the networks, number of episodes, and all the other parameters such as learning rate to fit your environment may solve the problem. However, it is not performing well in some environments. So, I changed to A2C because it shows better results.
This is the DDPG model and parameters that I got better results:

```
import os

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
label = 'DDPG_model'
rand_unif = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-3e-3,maxval=3e-3)
import var
winit = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
binit = tf.constant_initializer(0.01)
class CriticNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, sess, s_dim, a_dim, learning_rate=1e-3, tau=1e-3, gamma=0.995, hidden_unit_size=64):

        self.sess = sess
        self.s_dim = s_dim
        self.a_dim = a_dim
        self.hidden_unit_size = hidden_unit_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.tau = tau
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.seed = 0

        # Create the critic network
        self.inputs, self.action, self.out = self.buil_critic_nn(scope='critic')
        self.network_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='critic')

        # Target Network
        self.target_inputs, self.target_action, self.target_out = self.buil_critic_nn(scope='target_critic')
        self.target_network_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='target_critic')

        # Op for periodically updating target network with online network
        # weights with regularization
        self.update_target_network_params = [self.target_network_params[i].assign(
            tf.multiply(self.network_params[i], self.tau) + tf.multiply(self.target_network_params[i], 1. - self.tau))
                                             for i in range(len(self.target_network_params))]

        # Network target (y_i)
        self.predicted_q_value = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

        # Define loss and optimization Op
        self.loss = tf.losses.huber_loss(self.out,self.predicted_q_value, delta=0.5)
        self.optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
            self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
        if var.opt == 2:
            self.optimize = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=var.learning_rate, momentum=0.95,
                                                      epsilon=0.01).minimize(self.loss)
        elif var.opt == 0:
            self.optimize = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=var.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)

        # Get the gradient of the net w.r.t. the action.
        # For each action in the minibatch (i.e., for each x in xs),
        # this will sum up the gradients of each critic output in the minibatch
        # w.r.t. that action. Each output is independent of all
        # actions except for one.
        self.action_grads = tf.gradients(self.out, self.action)

    def buil_critic_nn(self, scope='network'):
        hid1_size = self.hidden_unit_size
        hid2_size = self.hidden_unit_size
        with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            state = tf.placeholder(name='c_states', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, self.s_dim])
            action = tf.placeholder(name='c_action', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, self.a_dim])

            net = tf.concat([state, action], 1)

            net1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net, units=1000, activation="linear",
                                   kernel_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                                   name='anet1')

            net2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net1, units=520, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                                   name='anet2')
            net3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net2, units=220, activation="linear", kernel_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                                   name='anet3')


            out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net3, units=1,
                                  kernel_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                                  name='anet_out')
            out = (tf.nn.softsign(out))


        return state, action, out

    def train(self, inputs, action, predicted_q_value):
        return self.sess.run([self.out, self.optimize], feed_dict={
            self.inputs: inputs,
            self.action: action,
            self.predicted_q_value: predicted_q_value
        })

    def predict(self, inputs, action):
        return self.sess.run(self.out, feed_dict={
            self.inputs: inputs,
            self.action: action
        })

    def predict_target(self, inputs, action):
        return self.sess.run(self.target_out, feed_dict={
            self.target_inputs: inputs,
            self.target_action: action
        })

    def action_gradients(self, inputs, actions):
        return self.sess.run(self.action_grads, feed_dict={
            self.inputs: inputs,
            self.action: actions
        })

    def update_target_network(self):
        self.sess.run(self.update_target_network_params)
    def return_loss(self, predict, inputs, action):
        return self.sess.run(self.loss ,feed_dict={
        self.predicted_q_value: predict, self.inputs: inputs,
            self.action: action})




class ActorNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, sess, s_dim, a_dim,lr=1e-4,  tau=1e-3, batch_size=64,action_bound=1):

        self.sess = sess
        self.s_dim = s_dim
        self.a_dim = a_dim
        self.act_min = 0
        self.act_max = 51

        self.hdim = 64
        self.lr = lr

        self.tau = tau  # Parameter for soft update
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.seed = 0
        self.action_bound = action_bound
        # Actor Network
        self.inputs, self.out , self.scaled_out =  self.create_actor_network(scope='actor')
        self.network_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='actor')

        # Target Network
        self.target_inputs, self.target_out, self.target_scaled_out = self.create_actor_network(scope='target_actor')
        self.target_network_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='target_actor')

        # Parameter Updating Operator
        self.update_target_network_params = [self.target_network_params[i].assign(
            tf.multiply(self.network_params[i], self.tau) + tf.multiply(self.target_network_params[i], 1. - self.tau))
            for i in range(len(self.target_network_params))]
        self.action_gradient = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.a_dim])
        # Gradient will be provided by the critic network
        self.actor_gradients = tf.gradients(self.scaled_out, self.network_params, -self.action_gradient)

        # Combine the gradients here
        self.unnormalized_actor_gradients = tf.gradients(self.out, self.network_params, -self.action_gradient)
        #         self.actor_gradients = list(map(lambda x: x/self.batch_size, self.unnormalized_actor_gradients))
        self.actor_gradients = [unnz_actor_grad / self.batch_size for unnz_actor_grad in
                                self.unnormalized_actor_gradients]

        # Optimizer
        self.optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(-self.lr).apply_gradients(zip(self.actor_gradients, self.network_params))


        if var.opt == 2:
            self.optimize = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=var.learning_rate, momentum=0.95, epsilon=0.01). \
                apply_gradients(zip(self.unnormalized_actor_gradients, self.network_params))
        elif var.opt == 0:
            self.optimize = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=var.learning_rate). \
                apply_gradients(zip(self.unnormalized_actor_gradients, self.network_params))

        self.num_trainable_vars = len(self.network_params) + len(self.target_network_params)

    def create_actor_network(self, scope='network'):
        hid1_size = self.hdim
        hid2_size = self.hdim

        with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            state = tf.placeholder(name='a_states', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, self.s_dim])

            net1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=state, units=1500, activation="linear", kernel_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                                  name='anet1')


            net2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net1, units=1250, activation="relu",kernel_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), name='anet2')



            out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net2, units=self.a_dim, kernel_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                                   name='anet_out')
            out=(tf.nn.sigmoid(out))
            scaled_out = tf.multiply(out, self.action_bound)
            # out = tf.nn.tanh(out)
        return state, out,scaled_out

    def train(self, inputs, a_gradient):
        self.sess.run(self.optimize, feed_dict={
            self.inputs: inputs,
            self.action_gradient: a_gradient
        })

    def predict(self, inputs):
        return self.sess.run(self.out, feed_dict={
            self.inputs: inputs
        })

    def predict_target(self, inputs):
        return self.sess.run(self.target_out, feed_dict={
            self.target_inputs: inputs
        })

    def update_target_network(self):
        self.sess.run(self.update_target_network_params)

    def get_num_trainable_vars(self):
        return self.num_trainable_vars

    def save_models(self, sess, model_path):
        """ Save models to the current directory with the name filename """
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        model_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "DDPGmodel" + str(var.n_vehicle) + "/" + model_path)
        saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=var.n_vehicle * var.n_neighbor)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(model_path)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(model_path))
        saver.save(sess, model_path, write_meta_graph=True)

    def save(self):
        print('Training Done. Saving models...')
        model_path = label + '/agent_'
        print(model_path)
        self.save_models(self.sess, model_path)

    def load_models(self, sess, model_path):
        """ Restore models from the current directory with the name filename """
        dir_ = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=var.n_vehicle * var.n_neighbor)
        model_path = os.path.join(dir_, "DDPGmodel" + str(var.n_vehicle) + "/" + model_path)
        saver.restore(self.sess, model_path)

    def load(self,sess):
        print("\nRestoring the model...")
        model_path = label + '/agent_'
        self.load_models(sess, model_path)
```

Parameters

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='provide arguments for DDPG agent')

    # agent parameters
    parser.add_argument('--actor-lr', help='actor network learning rate', default=var.learning_rateMADDPG)
    parser.add_argument('--critic-lr', help='critic network learning rate', default=var.learning_rateMADDPG_c2)

    parser.add_argument('--gamma', help='discount factor for critic updates', default=0.99)
    parser.add_argument('--tau', help='soft target update parameter', default=0.001)
    parser.add_argument('--buffer-size', help='max size of the replay buffer', default=100000)
    parser.add_argument('--minibatch-size', help='size of minibatch for minibatch-SGD', default=32)

    # run parameters
    parser.add_argument('--env', help='choose the gym env- tested on {Pendulum-v0}', default='Pendulum-v0')
    parser.add_argument('--random-seed', help='random seed for repeatability', default=1234)
    parser.add_argument('--max-episodes', help='max num of episodes to do while training', default=var.number_eps)
    parser.add_argument('--max-episode-len', help='max length of 1 episode', default=100)
    parser.add_argument('--render-env', help='render the gym env', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--use-gym-monitor', help='record gym results', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--monitor-dir', help='directory for storing gym results', default='./results/gym_ddpg')
    parser.add_argument('--summary-dir', help='directory for storing tensorboard info', default='./results/tf_ddpg')
```

To Select the Action use one of these mathods:

```
# action = np.argmax(actions)
 action = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(actions[0])), p=actions[0])
```

You can find different papers talk about this problem. For example in the paper `[1-5]`, the authors show some shortcomings of DDPG and shows why the ddpg algorithm fails to achieve convergence

- The  DDPG is designed for settings with continuous and often high-dimensional action spaces and the problem becomes very sharp as the number of agents increases.
- The second problem comes from the inability of DDPG to handle variability on the set of agents.
- The settings in real-life platforms however are quite dynamic, with agents arriving and leaving or their costs varying over time, and for an allocation algorithm to be applicable, it should be able to handle such variability.
- DDPG needs more steps to coverage.
- Changing the result shows that the algorithms that used the replay memory do not perform well in a changing environment because the stability problem where it is considered as one of the main problems when there are feeding observations into the model, the model cannot generalize properly from past experiences and these experiences are used inefficiently. In addition, these problems are raised where the increasing number of agents expands the state-action space exponentially.

[image]
[image]

1- Cai, Q., Filos-Ratsikas, A., Tang, P., & Zhang, Y. (2018, April). Reinforcement Mechanism Design for e-commerce. In Proceedings of the 2018 World Wide Web Conference (pp. 1339-1348).

2- Iqbal, S., & Sha, F. (2019, May). Actor-attention-critic for multi-agent reinforcement learning. In International Conference on Machine Learning (pp. 2961-2970). PMLR.

3- Foerster, J., Nardelli, N., Farquhar, G., Afouras, T., Torr, P. H., Kohli, P., & Whiteson, S. (2017, August). Stabilising experience replay for deep multi-agent reinforcement learning. In Proceedings of the 34th International Conference on Machine Learning-Volume 70 (pp. 1146-1155). JMLR. org.

4- Hou, Y., & Zhang, Y. (2019). Improving DDPG via Prioritized Experience Replay. no. May.

5- Wang, Y., & Zhang, Z. (2019, November). Experience Selection in Multi-agent Deep Reinforcement Learning. In 2019 IEEE 31st International Conference on Tools with Artificial Intelligence (ICTAI) (pp. 864-870). IEEE.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I will pay a close attention to A2C, though my problem is not so much related to multi-agent RL (agent 0, agent 1, etc. on my plot stand for separate simulations in the same environment).

Comment: The rules can be applied for single-agent and multi-agent and try the code above and see the results.